# How do I use fadeIn() in jQuery by using .addClass

Tags: jquery

Having this problem using fadeIn() in jQuery when applying it to addClass() (more like is this even possible):

Doesn't work!! here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("div").addClass('div_a').fadeIn(1000);

});
```

Should be simple for some...

Comment: Whats doesn't work in your code? Have you faded your div out? If it is already visible the fadein() function does nothing since your element is already visible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the element faded out when you start it to be able to fade it in. 
This example fades a div in, and adds a div_a class to the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").addClass('div_a').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
.div.div_a {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. In addition, I would like to scroll on the page and trigger the fadeIn(). I tried   if($(window).scrollTop() > $("elementID").height()), but it doesn't work correctly (the fadeIn happens without being triggered)....

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div").hide().addClass('div_a').fadeIn(1000);
 });`

Comment: Thanks, but now I want to trigger the fade in when I scroll the webpage to a certain <div>.